# how to get the previous state of the player in videojs

Tags: video.js

I'm using "videojs" to play videos on my site and i want to know how can i get the previous state of the player (playing, paused, etc).
I used to word with "jwplayer" and there was a variable called "oldstate" that did the work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle the state of the player with this code snippet:

```js
    var was_paying= false;

    player.on(['waiting', 'pause'], function () {
        was_playing= true;
    });

    player.on('playing', function () {
        was_playing= false;
    });
```

The `was_playing` variable acts as a flag to check whether the player was in a playing state or it was paused by the user or it was in a waiting mode because of the poor network connection.

If you know any better way to do this I'd be glad to know your solutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).